# Sum of PySpark array using SQL function AGGREGATE produces incorrect result when casting as float

Tags: apache-spark

The following code produces results that are slightly different from the correct result, and I was wondering if anyone can help identify why.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
import pyspark.sql.types as t
import pandas as pd

v1 = [24005, 24806874, 114187]
v2 = [24005, 24806872, 114189]
df = pd.DataFrame({"index": range(2), "arr": [v1, v2]})

schema = t.StructType(
    [t.StructField("index", t.IntegerType(), True),
     t.StructField("arr", t.ArrayType(t.LongType(), True)),
    ]
)

df = spark.createDataFrame(df, schema=schema)
df = df.withColumn(
    "sum",
    f.expr("aggregate(arr, cast(0 as float), (acc, x) -> acc + x)")
)
df.show(truncate=False)

# Output
#+-----+-------------------------+-----------+
#|index|arr                      |sum        |
#+-----+-------------------------+-----------+
#|0    |[24005, 24806874, 114187]|2.4945068E7|
#|1    |[24005, 24806872, 114189]|2.4945064E7|
#+-----+-------------------------+-----------+
```

However, updating `float` to `double` gives the correct result:

```
# Output
#+-----+-------------------------+-----------+
#|index|arr                      |sum        |
#+-----+-------------------------+-----------+
#|0    |[24005, 24806874, 114187]|2.4945066E7|
#|1    |[24005, 24806872, 114189]|2.4945066E7|
#+-----+-------------------------+-----------+
```

I would love to hear your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

The effective digits of the decimal part of 32-bit `floats` are usually 6-7 digits. Your calculation result is 8 digits, which is beyond the float range, so its accuracy cannot be guaranteed.